# Qt Mac OSX screen lock from application

Tags: c++, macos, qt

We have developed an Qt application for Mac OSX  in which we have used the following code to lock the screen.

```
system("/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend");
```

The code works as expected except sometime after locking, the screen freezes (a white/gray blank screen). We have to force shutdown the mac to unfreeze.

I have tested in Mac OSX 10.7.2, 10.7.4, 10.7.5.

I am not sure if its a problem of our app or the issue is caused by Mac itself?

Can anyone shed some light into this?

Thanks,

Comment: so your program should lock the screen like when you leave sleep?

Comment: yes, something like this.

Comment: if the `system()` call is similar to the windows version, it will block your application until it has finished. so maybe this will cause your program to stop and still won't let the os 'sleep' as well.

try to start it using the `QProcess` class described here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qprocess.html#details

Comment: @Zaiborg it seems to be an xscreensaver related issue. https://github.com/Razor-qt/razor-qt/issues/78